# null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-sound

i tried to play a sound using react native but i got this problem when i run the app :
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid')
, i think that that this problem caused by the package itself ,help please

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

var Sound = require('react-native-sound');


Sound.setCategory('Playback');

var audio = new Sound(
  'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3',
  null,
  error => {
    if (error) {
      console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
      return;
    }
    // if loaded successfully
    console.log(
      'duration in seconds: ' +
        audio.getDuration() +
        'number of channels: ' +
        audio.getNumberOfChannels(),
    );
  },
);
const App = () => {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    audio.setVolume(1);
    return () => {
      audio.release();
    };
  }, []);
  const playPause = () => {
    if (audio.isPlaying()) {
      audio.pause();
      setPlaying(false);
    } else {
      setPlaying(true);
      audio.play(success => {
        if (success) {
          setPlaying(false);
          console.log('successfully finished playing');
        } else {
          setPlaying(false);
          console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
        }
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playBtn} onPress={playPause}>
        <Ionicons
          name={playing ? 'ios-pause-outline' : 'ios-play-outline'}
          size={36}
          color={'#fff'}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  playBtn: {
    padding: 20,
  },
});
export default App;
```

i tried to install the package using yarn but it make the same problem
the app don't work when i run it in expo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use this package in Expo because it requires some native links, which needs a pure React Native project.

If you want to play sound using Expo, you can use the Audio API from the Expo SDK (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/)